# How can I float an an element to the right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

Hello everyone.
Guys how can I float the div(.footer-right) to the right side.
I tried (float: right), (right:0), and something like these but it didn't work?
Can anybody solve this problem???
Thanks in advance!!!

```css
.footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 50px;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 80px 0 16px 0;
  float: left;
}

.footer .fab {
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 24px 0 0;
}

.footer-right a {
  font-family: "Noto Serif", serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0 17px;
}

.footer-right {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="footer">
  <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>Facebook</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>Instagram</a>
  <a href="#  "><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>Linkedin</a>

  <div class="footer-right">
    <a href="">©2020 Grovemade</a>
    <a href="">Terms & Conditions</a>
    <a href="">Privacy Policy</a>
    <a href="">Site by Department </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting a float (which allows long text for example to flow under the element) or are you just wanting to get the whole footer-right onto the right hand side?

Comment: Float does not work in a flex container....remove `display:inline-flex`

Answer (score 1):

replace footer with this code

```
.footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 50px;
  /* display: inline-flex; */ 
  padding: 80px 0 16px 0;
  /* float: left; */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add these properties to your respective css classes and it will work.

```css
.footer{
 position: relative;
}
.footer-right{
 position: absolute;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it's not me. I can't even vote because my reputation is under 15 :) I'm new here bro

Comment: Your answer is overall a poor solution. With `position: absolute` you move that element out of flow and will cause a collision (overlapping of elements)  on smaller screens.

Comment: @tacoshy We can use display: flex and then justify-self: end as well. This won't break the flow but since justify-self is relatively new property some browsers might not support it.

Comment: it is not a new property. The only browser not supporting is IE11 which ahs been deprecated at the 16th August 2021. `margin-left: auto;` would work aswell in IE11. YOu can also simply remove `display: inine-flex` as mentioned in the comments. But as you see yourself, using `position: absolute` is a very poor solution as you have so many alternatives that would not cause potencial issues.